# Workings of loops

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop, iteration

I have two loops that finds the product of the items in a list. Seen below:

Loop A

```
product = 1
for i in [1, 2, 4, 8]:
   product *= i
print(product) # result= 64
```

Loop B

```
product = 1
i = iter([1, 2, 4, 8])
while True:
     try:
        product *= next(i)
     except StopIteration:
        break
print(product) # prints: 64
```

My question is what happens inside the for-loop that makes an explicit call of an iterator i.e.: iter([1,2,4,8]) necessary ?

Can't python discern that [1,2,4,8] is list hence an iterable as it did in the for loop?

Comment: `iter([1,2,4,8]) ` is in the while not the for loop what are you actually asking, how iter works or how a for loop works?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement

Comment: ...what? You can *see* the internal workings, Python is open source, but which distribution?

Comment: I mean with the while loop can't python discern that [1,2,4,8] is a list, hence is an utterable as it did in the for loop.

Comment: The loops don't care if it's a list or not. But in the while loop you are clearly doing something different: you are calling `next()` on it. You can't call next on a list, only in an iterator.

Comment: The ```for``` statement is designed to work with iterator types. [This](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) may give a hint.

Comment: For what it matters, what you did in loop A is essentially syntactic sugar for what you did in loop B. Iterating on an iterable with a for loop will create an iterator of the iterable and then `next()` that iterator until the `StopIteration` exception is raised at which point the for loop stops iterating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `for` statement in python is by definition an iterative loop. The `while` statement is non-iterative, and so an iterator must be created for it. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html):

`for`

> Python’s for statement iterates over the items of any sequence (a list or a string), in the order that they appear in the sequence.

`while`

> The while loop executes as long as the condition (here: `True`) remains true.

Loop A and Loop B represent two different ways of accomplishing the same thing, through a different method.

**Loop A** uses the `for` statement to iterate through the given list [1, 2, 4, 8]

**Loop B** uses a `while` statement, which by definition is non-iterative, and continues until given a false condition, or by `break`.

In order to end the while loop, **Loop B** establishes an iterator across the list with `i = iter()`. When `next(i)` reaches the end of the iterator `i`, it triggers the exception, which uses `break` to exit the `while` loop.

**Loop A** would be considered by many to be the more pythonic and safer way to compute the product in this manner.

Answer (score 1):

You have used [`iter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter) in `while` loop which return an *[iterator object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types)* of your current object, so then you can all the [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) function on it to Retrieve the next item from the iterator.This can help you to access to an iterable object's items without using a `for` loop, also since that iterators are one shot iterables you can not iterate over the `i` again.